# Cant select radio buttons inside the form in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button, radio-group

It won't allow me to change the radio button inside the form, the value also does not change no matter what is selected. I have tried the code outside the form and it works fine but when i put it inside the form then it stops working for reasons I do not know.

```
FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('New User'),
                  content: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Positioned(
                        right: -40.0,
                        top: -40.0,
                        child: InkResponse(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            child: Icon(Icons.close),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Form(
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: nameController,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Name',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: surnameController,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Surname',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: userController,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Username',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: passController,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Password',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: mobileController,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Mobile num',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: emailController,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Email',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              //radioButtons
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "What is your gender?",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                    ),
                                    Divider(),
                                    RadioListTile(
                                      title: Text("Male"),
                                      value: "male",
                                      groupValue: gender,
                                      onChanged: (value) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          gender = value.toString();
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    RadioListTile(
                                      title: Text("Female"),
                                      value: "female",
                                      groupValue: gender,
                                      onChanged: (value) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          gender = value.toString();
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    RadioListTile(
                                      title: Text("Other"),
                                      value: "other",
                                      groupValue: gender,
                                      onChanged: (value) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          gender = value.toString();
                                        });
                                      },
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: FloatingActionButton(
                                  child: Text("Submit"),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    //createUser();
                                    print(gender);

                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  },
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.person),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
```

it has a few text fields and then the radio buttons, the gender variable is declared as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Because you are assigned a value in the dialog. Just Wrap Your Alert Dialog Widget with statfulBuilder and then stateState.

example

```
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: const Text('New User'),
              content: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    right: -40,
                    top: -40,
                    child: InkResponse(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: const CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                        child: Icon(Icons.close),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Form(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: nameController,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Name',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: surnameController,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Surname',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: userController,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Username',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: passController,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Password',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: mobileController,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Mobile num',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: emailController,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Email',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          //radioButtons
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                const Text(
                                  'What is your gender?',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                ),
                                const Divider(),
                                RadioListTile(
                                  title: const Text('Male'),
                                  value: 'male',
                                  groupValue: gender,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      gender = value.toString();
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                RadioListTile(
                                  title: const Text('Female'),
                                  value: 'female',
                                  groupValue: gender,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      gender = value.toString();
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                RadioListTile(
                                  title: const Text('Other'),
                                  value: 'other',
                                  groupValue: gender,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      gender = value.toString();
                                    });
                                  },
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: FloatingActionButton(
                              child: const Text('Submit'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                //createUser();
                                print(gender);

                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  },
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  child: Icon(Icons.person),
);
```